# Using Mid and InStr to extract data from hyphenated string

Tags: ms-access-2016

Below are examples of three rows of what the values of column-A in my Access query looks like, all are varying numbers of characters and separated by hyphens:

**Column_A**

10-123-20000000-JaneBank-JaneBank1001-Regions

100-1234-40000-NeilBank-NeilBank1201-Regions

10-12125-2232456-ABCAcct-ABCAcct2122-Regions

So from these rows, I would like to return only the value between the fourth and fifth hyphens of each row

Your assistance woukd be ery much appreciated

In Column-B I have tried the following two expressions:

Column-B: Mid([Column-A],InStr([Column-A],"-")+1,InStr(Right([Column-A],Len([Column-A])-InStr([Column-A],"-")),".")-1)

Column-B:Trim([Column_1],InStr([Column-A],"-")+1,InStr(InStr([Column-A]."-")+1,[Column-A],"-")-InStr([Column_A],"-")-1))

I have tried various combination of Right, Left & Mid with variation of Instr and InsrtRev. Can someone please assist me with the correct code for my query. These two resulted in the value between the second and third hyphens only.

Your assistance woukd be ery much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

DataMint,

Use the Split() function:

Example below run in VBE Immediate Mode.

```
x="10-123-20000000-JaneBank-JaneBank1001-Regions"
y=split(x,"-",-1)
?y(4)
JaneBank1001
```

Adjust the code subscript to get your desired item.